# Want to show progress bar while moving to the previous page from the current page

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, download, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I want to show progress bar when I'm moving from the current page to previous page. so my scenario is like in the current page I'm downloading 20-25 images and while downloading the images want to move from the current page to the previous screen and show the progress bar in a RecyclerView and in the upper area of the page(till downloading completed).

So how Can I achieve it? I'm not getting like how we can show the progress from current page to previous page? Please help me out. Any help will be appreciated.

ImageDownload()

```
private fun downloadImage() {
    GlobalScope.launch(dispatcherProvider.io()) {
        for (angle in 0..340 step 20) {
            dataHandler.MyRequestHandler.getImage(url.replace("340", "%03d".format(angle)), "%03d".format(angle)) { response: Response ->

                if (response.body() != null && response.isSuccessful && response.networkResponse()!!.code() == 200) {
                    if (isDownload) {
                        activity.lifecycleScope.launch {
                            try {
                                isDownload = true
                                val imageByteArray = response.body()?.source()?.readByteArray()
                                imageEntity = viewModel.imageEntityConverter(ImageModels("xyz", number, "%03d".format(angle), "ownImage", imageByteArray))
                                viewModel.insertNumber(imageEntity)
                                activity.popSubPage()
                                activity.showSubPage(CarSelectionSite(activity), false)
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                Timber.e(e, "Failed to download image")
                                showErrorMessageDialog(R.string.failed, R.string.general_request_error)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (response.networkResponse() != null && response.networkResponse()!!.code() == 404) {
                    showErrorMessageDialog(R.string.error_fin_not_found_title, R.string.error_fin_not_found_message)
                    return@getBBDCarImage
                } else {
                    showErrorMessageDialog(R.string.failed, R.string.general_request_error)
                    return@getBBDCarImage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Fragments ?

Comment: So when want to navigate from one fragment to another fragment who want to show progress bar is the only thing you want right ?

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar no actually I know when to navigate but Am asking like how can I show the progress of downloading the images from the current subpage(where images are downloading) to previous subpage(where want to show the progress bar for download process)

Comment: What does your pages look like ? Can you upload screenshot and code for the same

Comment: So you have a recyclerview in one fragment , where on + click you go to next fragment and there on click of download , download starts and you want the progress of the dialog on previous fragment , right ?

Comment: Are you using ViewModels ?

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar Yes...I'm using

Comment: Upload the code especially the function  you are using to download images

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar have added image download function

Answer (score 1):

For your UseCase , you just need to implement a Shared ViewModel between your fragments . I have not implemented your UseCase(Since I don't have your code ) . I have created my UseCase . It is a basic application using Navigation Component to navigate between fragments and fragment-ktx for easily creating a shared ViewModel .

First add the fragment - ktx dependency in your gradle file :

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6"
```

Then first create a Shared View Model . Here I have just created a ViewModel with a function wherein it counts from   20 to 1 with a tiny delay and then updates the textView of the countDown it is current on . I have used MutableLiveData to communicate with fragments . You should have your download function here and you have to update your textView using MutableLiveData / KotlinFlow

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _progress: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()
    val progress: LiveData<Int>
        get() = _progress

    suspend fun printFrom0to20() {
        viewModelScope.launch {

            for (i in 20 downTo 0) {
                _progress.postValue(i)
                delay(100)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have two fragments . In the first there is a button which navigates to the second Fragment and a textView wherein it shows the progress where it is current at though the function is called in the second fragment . In your scenario , your progress of how many images have been downloaded will be shown though not being on the fragment where it was started . Here is how the fragment look like . Here remember to use **activitViewModel** which create SharedViewModel

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private lateinit var moveToSecondFragment: Button
    private lateinit var progressValue: TextView


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
        moveToSecondFragment = view.findViewById(R.id.moveToSecondFragment)
        progressValue = view.findViewById(R.id.currentProgress)
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.progress.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            progressValue.text = it.toString()
        })

        moveToSecondFragment.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment)
        }
    }

}
```

Now in the second Fragment ,  I have added a button which starts the countDown also a button to navigate to last fragment and also a textView which shows current progress .

```
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

    private lateinit var startDownload : Button
    private lateinit var moveToFirstFragment : Button
    private lateinit var currentProgress : TextView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
        moveToFirstFragment = view.findViewById(R.id.moveToFirstFragment)
        startDownload = view.findViewById(R.id.startDownload)
        currentProgress = view.findViewById(R.id.currentProgress2)
        return  view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        startDownload.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                viewModel.printFrom0to20()
            }
        }

        moveToFirstFragment.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_secondFragment_to_firstFragment)
        }

        viewModel.progress.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,{
            currentProgress.text = it.toString()
        })

    }


}
```

If you adopt to this code , you will see that the countdown can be seen at both the fragment . Using SharedViewModel concept you can create your own version as per your UseCase .

This is the demo of the application [image]

Comment: Ask for doubts if any