# Pass value of a MutableLiveData of ViewModels

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm very very new to Android and I'm trying to understand/integrate Data Binding.

I think I'm missing something since it always displays `null`

Here is my `ViewModel`

```
class LockDetailsModel: ViewModel() {
    var name = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun setName(name: String) {
        this.name.value = name
    }
```

In my `LockActivity`, I set the value of `name` based on a certain field.

```
val viewModel: LockDetailsModel by viewModels()
viewModel.setName(unitName.toString())
```

And in my other activity, which displays the layout, this is what I did to bind the model

```
 val viewModel: LockDetailsModel by viewModels()
 binding: ActivityConnectLockBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_connect_lock)
 binding.lockDetails = viewModel
 binding.lifecycleOwner = this
```

It displays null :(

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I am assuming your both activity isn't sharing your mutabeLiveData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind you getting `null` value is because you are using `different` viewModel `instances` in both the activities , thus the value stored by you in first Activity cannot be obtained in the Second activity . You need to have `SharedViewModel` between both the activities , which is not possible due to `Single Activity principle` . So to implement logic that you want to implement you need to have `Fragments` and make use of `fragment-ktx`  library to easily create `SharedViewModel` .If you want an `example` you can refer to my answer here :

> [Want to show progress bar while moving to the previous page from the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68993429/want-to-show-progress-bar-while-moving-to-the-previous-page-from-the-current-pag/69001569#69001569)

The above answer describes how to get progress of a download started in one activity into another .